# Use Freeswitch Modules in Asterisk 1.6

Tags: installation, asterisk, freeswitch

I need to run **Freeswitch** modules in **Asterisk**, *Voice Recognition* in particular, because Pocketsphinx can be used there directly without the bottleneck of UniMRCP (which is slow and not really open source anymore). For Freeswitch is based on Asterisk and can even run Asterisk-Dialplans I thought it might be possible to *compile a custom version of Asterisk including one or more Freeswitch modules*. Does anyone have experience with that and can hint how to proceed there ?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is definitly not possible.

I have experience porting module from Freeswitch to asterisk, cost is like 30hr for simple module(expert time).

You can use EAGI which will remove UniMRCP at all.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I'll then port the needed aspects in an own module, I just hoped I could avoid the time :D

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is kind of possible, but not very easy to achieve. Sangoma did a brief summary what one has to keep in mind: https://de.slideshare.net/MoisesSilva6/freeswitch-modules-for-asterisk-developers